# Método delete en laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Muy buenas noches caballeros, tengo un pequeño inconveniente en laravel con la eliminación de registros, lo que sucede es que al asignarle la ruta con su respectivo controlador y su método, me aparece el error no message, revisando no he encontrado cual es la razón de este error, adjunto 3 partes fundamentales de mi código en laravel

Lugar donde esta la acción para eliminar

```
introducir el código aquí
@foreach ($patient as $patients )
    <tr>
        <th>{{$patients->name}}</th>
        <td>{{$patients->age}}</td>
        <td>{{$patients->correo}}</td>
        <td>{{$patients->id_paciente}}</td>
        <td>
            <form action="{{ route('patients.destroy', $patients) }}" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }} {{ method_field('delete') }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">Eliminar</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Rutas creadas en la aplicación, la ultima es con la que elimino

```
introducir el código aquí
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
 });

 Auth::routes();

 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

 Route::get('/pacientes', 'UserController@show');

 Route::get('/paciente/nuevo', 'UserController@create')->name('create');

 Route::post('/paciente', 'UserController@store');

 Route::delete('/pacientes/{patient}', 'UserController@destroy')- 
 >name('patients.destroy');
```

Por ultimo el controlador que genera la acción

```
introducir el código aquí
public function destroy(Patient $patient)
{
    $patient->delete();
    return redirect('pacientes');
}
```

Comment: Cuando creas la acción de los formularios `{{ route('patients.destroy', $patients) }}`, la ruta no debería ser `{{ route('patients.destroy', $patient->id) }}`?

Comment: Pues se supone que como laravel trabaja con eloquent , el detecta el dato que esta solicita ejemplo su id y lo toma sin necesidad de especificar, pero también intente eso pero aparece otro error diferente, que es que llega al controlador pero no se ejecuta la acción para eliminar

Comment: Entonces prueba haciendo un dos var_dumps, ambos en el metodo destroy, pero uno con $patient y otro con $patient->delete(), a ver que devuelven.

Comment: Francisco Garrido, exactamente fue algo parecido a lo que tu me dijiste, era que tenia que pasar a el modelo que esta relacionado con esa tabla una referencia de cual es mi llave primaria, ya que eloquent las toma todas como si fueran ID, entonces como en mi base de datos no es id sino id_paciente, solo agregue su referencia especifica en el modelo

Answer (score 0):

Este problema lo resolví de la siguiente manera, como laravel al trabajar con **eloquent** el deduce que nuestra tabla tiene su llave primaria como **id** y al no encontrarse mi tabla con ese nombre el me dice que no encuentra la referencia a esa tabla , lo cual se tiene que especificar directamente en el **modelo** de esa tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
introducir el código aquí
class Patient extends Model
{
  protected $table = "patient";
  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'correo', 'age',
  ];
  protected $primaryKey = 'id_paciente';

}
```

Como podemos observar en la ultima referencia lo único que agregue fue su *llave primaria* y el nombre como lo tengo en mi base de datos, y de esta forma el entiende que ya mi tabla tiene su llave primaria con ese nombre y ejecuta la acción

Comment: ese era un buen detalle que para futuras referencias debes agregar a tu pregunta